# How to use pytest session fixture return value in a test class

Tags: python, pytest

I am creating automation framework where in few parameters I have kept in a separate JSON file.
I have written the below fixture which would load the data from the JSON file in conftest.py.

```
import json

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def get_config_values():
    with open('./Resources/config.json') as f:
        config_values = json.load(f)
    return config_values
```

I have kept the scope as session so that I do not need to load them for every test class.
I am intending to use this return value in all the test classes which are in the below way

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("get_config_values")
class TestConf:

    def test_conf_test1(self):
        print(f"Test for user a")
        print(self.config_values["a"])

    def test_conf_test2(self):
        print(f"Test for user b")
        print(self.config_values["b"])
```

I am unable to use the return value in the the tests. I have tried below ways-

```
print(self.config_values["b"])
print(get_config_values["b"])
```

Please can someone help me how can we use session fixture return values in tests.
Or if there is any better way to achieve this.

Comment: Shouldn't it be defined as an argument to the test methods, `def test_conf_test(self, config_values):`? See e.g. https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html#autouse-fixtures-xunit-setup-on-steroids

Comment: Yes. I wanted to avoid calling it for every test as there might be hundreds of tests and every time it will load the json file for the values. Hence, I had made the fixture of session scope. Should I change the scope of the fixture as well then?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, `usefixtures` can't be used in this way, that is to return values to each of your test methods. You'd use this for like cleanup tasks like in the example [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.8.7/fixture.html#using-fixtures-from-classes-modules-or-projects).

For what you're asking about, you'd need your fixture as a parameter:

```
class TestConf:

    def test_conf_test1(self, get_config_values):
        print(f"Test for user a")
        print(get_config_values["a"])

    def test_conf_test2(self, get_config_values):
        print(f"Test for user b")
        print(get_config_values["b"])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. `usefixture` I had seen in various questions answered in this forum used for including a fixture for class. Hence, I tried using that fixture. Also, as I wanted to avoid calling the fixture for every method I was thinking to call it once using `usefixtures`.